# How to upload file in Nativescript Vue

Tags: file-upload, vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am working with NativeScript Vue 2 (NativeScript 4.2.2).

I need to upload a file from the app to a PHP server through an API.

This is the code I use... the server seems to get "file" as "[object Object]".

```html
<template>
    <Page>
      <StackLayout class="btn btn-grey" @tap="selectPicture()">
        <Label text="upload"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
      
      <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="Submit" @tap="submit()"></Button>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
import {Image} from 'tns-core-modules/ui/image';
import {File, knownFolders, path} from 'tns-core-modules/file-system';
import {ImageSource} from 'tns-core-modules/image-source';

import * as camera from 'nativescript-camera';
import * as imagepicker from 'nativescript-imagepicker';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectPicture() {
      const context = imagepicker.create({
        mode: this.multiple ? 'multiple' : 'single',
        minimumNumberOfSelection: 1,
        maximumNumberOfSelection: 1,
      });

      context
        .authorize()
        .then(() => context.present())
        .then((selection) => {
          selection.forEach((selected) => {
            let imageSource = new ImageSource();

            imageSource.fromAsset(selected)
              .then(() => {
                if (selected.android) {
                  this.saveFile(selected.android.toString());
                } else {
                  const ios = selected.ios;

                  if (ios.mediaType === PHAssetMediaType.Image) {
                    const opt = PHImageRequestOptions.new();
                    opt.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersion.Current;

                    PHImageManager.defaultManager()
                      .requestImageDataForAssetOptionsResultHandler(ios, opt, (imageData, dataUTI, orientation, info) => {
                      this.saveFile(info.objectForKey('PHImageFileURLKey').toString());
                    });
                  }
                }
              });
          });
        });
      },
      
      saveFile(source, saveIt = false) {
        const image = new Image();
        const folderPath = knownFolders.documents().path;

        image.src = source;

        const fileName = image.src.toString().split('/').pop();
        const filePath = path.join(folderPath, fileName);
        
        if (saveIt) {
          const imageSource = new ImageSource();
          const saved = imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, 'png');

          if (!saved) {
            console.log('[UploadFile] - Cannot save file!');
          }
        }
        
        this.value = File.fromPath(filePath);
        console.log('[UploadField] -->', fileName);
      },
      
      submit() {
        const params = new FormData();
        params.append('file', this.value);
      
        axios({
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
          method: 'POST',
          params,
        })
          .then((response) => console.log(response));
      },
  },
  

};
</script>
```

Cum autem commodis intervallata temporibus convivia longa et noxia coeperint apparari vel distributio sollemnium sportularum, anxia deliberatione tractatur an exceptis his quibus vicissitudo debetur, peregrinum invitari conveniet, et si digesto plene consilio id placuerit fieri, is adhibetur qui pro domibus excubat aurigarum aut artem tesserariam profitetur aut secretiora quaedam se nosse confingit.

Comment: Please remove unnecessary text that deteriorates the quality of the question

Comment: @SebaGra I wish I could... Stackoverflow won't let me submit without "extra" content. Hit them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Muti-part content type is not supported by the regular XHR (axios) request. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/59), you might want to register your vote and subscribe to the issue for further updates.

Meanwhile the workaround is to POST your file content as base64 string or use [nativescript-background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http#multipartupload) plugin which supports multi-part upload.

Comment: Thank you !! I did see those nativescript-background-http examples but never seen that it was the only workaround...